# Prove there are uncountably many syndetic sets

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Here is a sketch of my thought of proving it but I encounter some problems. Following the thought of Cantor's diagonal argument so firstly using indicator functions $1_s$, (S is a syndetic set) translate S into 0-1 sequence. S1 responds to a 0-1sequence, S2 responds to a 0-1 sequence and goes on. Then assume there is a one-to-one relation between these syndetic set(0-1 sequences) and $\Bbb{N}$. Finally construct a new syndetic set(maybe choosing one element from each 0-1 sequence,but how?) which does not occur in the enumeration. But I just cannot figure out how to construct such 0-1 sequences. Can anyone help or have any other solution?

Remark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syndetic_set, or in other word, syndetic set is a set which just has bounded gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\sigma=\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ let

$$S(\sigma)=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{2n+1:b_n=1\}\;;$$

clearly $S(\sigma)$ is syndetic, and the map $\sigma\mapsto S(\sigma)$ is injective. Thus, there are $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$ syndetic subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you! So you firstly give a set of 0-1 sequences that is injective with ℕ, and then construct syndetic sets which are injective to these 0-1 sequences. Here just few point not clear, first $b_n$ represents every 0-1 sequence right, but what does $b_n$ =1 mean? And does $\omega$ have a specific meaning? Thank you!

Comment: @UserQ: You may be more familiar with the alternative notation $2^{\aleph_0}$ for my $2^\omega$; either way, it’s just $\mathfrak{c}$, the cardinality of $\Bbb R$ and of $\wp(\Bbb N)$. \\ No, $\sigma$ represents an arbitrary $0$-$1$ sequence; $b_n$ is the $n$-th term of the sequence. The idea is to keep every even natural number, since this makes the set syndetic, and then to keep a subset of the odd numbers that corrsponds to the positions of the $1$s in the sequence $\sigma$. If $\sigma$ started $\langle 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1\rangle$, for instance, $S(\sigma)$ would contain odd numbers ...

Comment: ... $2\cdot1+1=3,2\cdot4+1=9$, and $2\cdot8+1=17$ (and possibly some larger ones). (Note: for me $0\in\Bbb N$, so those three $1$s are in positions $1,4$, and $8$, not $2,5$, and $9$.)

Comment: @ Brian This is brilliant. Thank you! And I agree 0 $\in\Bbb{N}$

Comment: @UserQ: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are countably many syndetic sets $S_1, S_2, S_3,\dotsc$. 
We now construct a syndetic set $S$ with $S\neq S_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, what gives a contradiction.

Let's define recursive a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ by
$$x_0:= 1, x_{k+1}=\min \{m\in \mathbb{N}\mid m>x_{k}+2, m \in S_{k+1}\}.$$

Define
$$S:=\{n\in \mathbb{N} \mid n\neq x_i \quad \forall i\in \mathbb{N}_0\}.$$

Then $x_i\in S_i\setminus S \quad \forall i\in \mathbb{N}$ and so $S\neq S_i\quad \forall i\in \mathbb{N}$ and $S$ is syndetic because the gaps in $S$ are not bigger than one missing natural number.